# How to backup and restore a kubernetes master node?

Tags: kubernetes, backup, restore

There is a k8s single master node, I need to back it up and restore on a different server with different ip addresses. I googled this topic and found a solution -
https://elastisys.com/2018/12/10/backup-kubernetes-how-and-why/

Everything looked easy; so, I followed the instruction and got a copy of the certificates and a snapshot of the etcd database. Then I used the second script to restore the node on a different server. It did not go well this time. It gave me a bunch of errors related to mismatching the certificates and server's local ip addresses.

As far as I understood, when a kubernetes cluster is initializing, it creates a set of certificates assigned to the original server's ip addresses and I cannot just back it up and restore somewhere else.

So, how to backup a k8s master node and restore it?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you added an extra flag to the kubeadm init command (`--ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd`) to acknowledge that we want to use the pre-existing data.

Do the following steps:

- replace the IP address in all config files in `/etc/kubernetes`
- back up `/etc/kubernetes/pki`
- identify certs in `/etc/kubernetes/pki` that have the old IP address
  as an alt name - **1st** step
- delete both the cert and key for each of them (for me it was just
  apiserver and etcd/peer)
- regenerate the certs using kubeadm alpha phase certs - **2nd** step
- identify configmap in the kube-system namespace that referenced
  the old IP - **3rd** step
- manually edit those configmaps
- restart kubelet and docker (to force all containers to be
  recreated)

**1.**

```
/etc/kubernetes/pki# for f in $(find -name "*.crt"); do openssl x509 -in $f -text -noout > $f.txt; done
/etc/kubernetes/pki# grep -Rl 12\\.34\\.56\\.78 .
./apiserver.crt.txt
./etcd/peer.crt.txt
/etc/kubernetes/pki# for f in $(find -name "*.crt"); do rm $f.txt; done
```

**2.**

```
/etc/kubernetes/pki# rm apiserver.crt apiserver.key
/etc/kubernetes/pki# kubeadm alpha phase certs apiserver
...
/etc/kubernetes/pki# rm etcd/peer.crt etcd/peer.key
/etc/kubernetes/pki# kubeadm alpha phase certs etcd-peer
```

...
**3.**

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get cm -o yaml | less
...
$ kubectl -n kube-system edit cm ...
```

Take a look here: [master-backup](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338).

**UPDATE:**

During replacing master nodes and changing IP you cannot contact the api-server to change the configmaps in step 4. Moreover if you have single master k8s cluster connection between worker nodes will be interrupted till new master will be up.

To ensure connection between master and worker nodes during master replacement you have to create [HA cluster](https://searchdisasterrecovery.techtarget.com/definition/high-availability-cluster-HA-cluster).

The certificate is signed for {your-old-IP-here} and secure communication can't then happen to {your-new-ip-here}

You can add more IPs in the certificate in beforehand though...

The api-server certificate is signed for hostname kubernetes, so you can add that as an alias to the new IP address in `/etc/hosts` then do k`ubectl --server=https://kubernetes:6443 ....` .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, the main idea is to replace the certificates. If I do that what will happen with worker nodes? Will they loose connection with the master?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please let me know if it helps. for future community you can upvote and accept it.

Comment: "Moreover if you have single master k8s cluster connection between worker nodes will be interrupted since new master will be up." So, basicaly changing the certs will destroy the cluster? I exepected them (worker nodes) to reconnect after master recovery and keep working. Let me explain my concerns. I have a master node and a few worker ones. Something happened with the master node and I lost it. I create a new one with the backup files I have.After restoring a new master node, I need to recreate the certs and update some configs. The question is what will happen with the worker nodes?

Comment: I have made mistake I wrote "since" instead "till". So basically after joining new master node you have to login to each worker node and update the kubelet configuration to point to the new Kubernetes master. Often times this file is found at /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf. Restart the kubelet service after making this change. Then your cluster will be up and connection between nodes will be enabled. Do you need some extra information ?

Comment: Just one more question -  What to update in the kubelet configuration? Do I need to changes just master node's ip adresses in the workers'  /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf? Thanks!

Comment: On workers nodes you have to replace the IP address in all config files in /etc/kubernetes and restart kubelet and docker - take a look on steps I have mention in instruction. Do you need more information ? If my answer is helpful please upvote and accept to be more visible for future community.